# Return string column with appended row number

Tags: sql, postgresql, row-number

I have a need to get the max number of records from a table and concatenate that number at the end of the field name, starting at 1 and ending at the max number of records:

| field1 | cnt |
| --- | --- |
| Car | 4 |
| Truck | 3 |

The final results need to be exportable in the format:

```
Car|1
Car|2
Car|3
Car|4
Truck|1
Truck|2
Truck|3
```

I cant use `RAISE` as I need more than a message in this instance. It has to be data output so the results can be used downstream.

Comment: You mention a *"number of records"*, but show a single row with a number. It's unclear what the underlying table actually contains. It's also unclear what defines the sort order. Or do only want to output the single columns as shown? Please show your table definition (`CREATE TABLE` script), some sample rows and your version of Postgres.

Comment: The source table is a hot mess.  Incredibly wide so I'm taking a subset of the source data and creating a view to give me only what I need:  Basically a summary of field1 and a count.  The raw data is inconsequential.

Something like select field1, count(field1) as cnt from mytable group by field1.

Comment: "I need ..." is not a question, and you should have showed what you tried see: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Luuk - That is a fair statement.  Thanks for the feedback...I'll be sure to correct that with future posts and make sure that they are questions with what I've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's your table (matching your description):

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl1 (
  tbl_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, field1 text
);
```

Then `row_number()` works:

```sql
SELECT field1 || '|' || row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY field1)
FROM   tbl1;
```

If that's your table (your sample data):

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl2 (
  tbl_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, field1 text
, cnt int
);
```

Then `generate_series()` does the job:

```sql
SELECT field1 || '|' ||  g
FROM   tbl2, generate_series(1, cnt) g;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hmIL51D0)

Neither loop nor recursion are needed either way.

Comment: I keep forgetting about the implicit `LATERAL` for table functions used in `FROM` clauses which makes `tbl2, generate_series(1, cnt) g` equivalent to `tbl2 CROSS JOIN LATERAL generate_series(1, cnt) g`. Despite being more verbose, I prefer the explicit `CROSS JOIN` to just a `,`. I've seen too many accidental Cartesian products caused by the latter. I'm indifferent as to whether or not `LATERAL` is explicitly specified.

Answer (score 0):

Below are two approaches to achieving the described results. The first uses a recursive common table expression (CTE) and is a close analog to loops in procedural languages. When working with databases, it is useful to break away from procedural thinking and instead embrace set based approaches. A set based approach is demonstrated in the second query.

```
WITH RECURSIVE parms(field1, cnt) AS (
  VALUES ('Car', 4),
         ('Truck', 3)
),
cte(field1, cnt, n) AS (
  SELECT parms.field1, parms.cnt, 1 AS n
    FROM parms
   WHERE parms.cnt > 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT cte.field1, cte.cnt, cte.n + 1 AS n
    FROM cte
   WHERE cte.n < cte.cnt
)
SELECT cte.field1 || '|' || cte.n::text AS result
  FROM cte
 ORDER BY cte.field1, cte.n;
```

```
WITH parms(field1, cnt) AS (
  VALUES ('Car', 4),
         ('Truck', 3)
),
c AS (
  SELECT generate_series(1, MAX(parms.cnt)) AS n
    FROM parms
)
SELECT parms.field1 || '|' || c.n::text AS result
  FROM parms
    JOIN c ON c.n <= parms.cnt
 ORDER BY parms.field1, c.n;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's use a temporary table with integers until .... well basically the max number that will be needed, like (`SELECT max(cnt) FROM mytable;`), but let's stick to `10` for now:

```
with recursive abc as (
    select 1 as x 
    union all 
    select x+1 
    from abc 
    where x<10) 
select * from abc;
```

Then you can do an INNER JOIN:

```
with recursive abc as (
    select 1 as x 
    union all 
    select x+1 
    from abc 
    where x<10) 
select * 
from mytable
inner join abc on abc.x <= mytable.cnt
order by field1, x;
```

or, if we really need the desired output:

```
with recursive abc as (
    select 1 as x 
    union all 
    select x+1 
    from abc 
    where x<10) 
select CONCAT(field1,'|',x) as result 
from mytable
inner join abc on abc.x <= mytable.cnt
order by field1, x;
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZK1e4Rs0)

Comment: This would work if I knew for sure that I could set x < 10.  I guess there would be nothing wrong with setting this to an arbitrarily high number knowing that the recursion would never need it.

Comment: or you could set it to: `(SELECT MAX(cnt) FROM mytable)`